# Put one div below the other

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 div's. 1 div on the left with a col-lg-6. 1 div next to it also with col-lg-6. And i have a third div with col-lg-6. I want the 3rd div to always be below div 1, even if div 3 becomes big.

my current code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Toe voegen
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="tabbable">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                                <li class="active"><a href="#producten"
                                                      data-toggle="tab"
                                                      data-target="#producten, #productenoverzicht">Producten</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#promoties" data-toggle="tab"
                                       data-target="#promoties, #promotiesoverzicht">Promoties</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#sterartikelken" data-toggle="tab"
                                       data-target="#sterartikelken, #sterartikelkenoverzicht">Sterartikelen</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#T4" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#T4, #T4overzicht">T4</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="gadget-add-list"><a href="#gadgets"
                                                            data-toggle="tab"
                                                            data-target="#gadgets, #gadgetoverzicht">Gadgets</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#lossestukken"
                                       data-toggle="tab" data-target="#lossestukken, #lossestukkenoverzicht">Lossestukken</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="artikelenVoucher-add-list"><a
                                        href="#artikelenVoucher" data-toggle="tab"
                                        data-target="#artikelenVoucher, #artikelenvouchersvoucheroverzicht">Voucher</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="producten">
                                <div class="container-fluid">

                                    <label for="selectcatagorie">Categorie</label><select
                                        class="form-control" id="selectcatagorie">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteer een
                                            categorie
                                        </option>
                                        <?php

                                        foreach (db_select("SELECT * FROM presse_wit_categorie ORDER BY code ASC ") as $item) {
                                            echo '<option ';
                                            echo 'value = "' . $item['GUID'] . '">';
                                            echo '(' . $item['code'] . ') ' . $item['description'];
                                            echo '</ option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                                    <label for="selectproduct">Product</label><select id="selectproduct"
                                                                                      class="form-control"
                                                                                      style="visibility: hidden">

                                    </select>

                                    <label for="aantalproduct">Aantal</label><input id="aantalproduct"
                                                                                    class="form-control"

                                                                                    type="number"
                                                                                    value="1"/>

                                    <br>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                                onclick="addProduct('')"
                                                id="addproductbutton">
                                            Voeg
                                            toe!
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="promoties">
                                <label for="selectPromotie">Promotie:</label><select id="selectPromotie"
                                                                                     class="form-control">

                                </select>
                                <label for="aantalPromoties">Aantal:</label><input id="aantalPromoties"
                                                                                   class="form-control"
                                                                                   type="number"
                                                                                   value="1"
                                />

                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="addPromotie('')"
                                            id="addpromotiebutton">
                                        Voeg
                                        toe!
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sterartikelken">
                                <label for="selectSterArtikel">Ster Artikel:</label><select
                                    id="selectSterArtikel"
                                    class="form-control">

                                </select>
                                <label for="aantalSterArtikel">Aantal:</label><input id="aantalSterArtikel"
                                                                                     class="form-control"
                                                                                     type="number"
                                                                                     value="1"
                                />

                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="addSterartikel('')"
                                            id="addSterArtikelbutton">
                                        Voeg
                                        toe!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="T4">
                                <label for="selectT4">T4:</label><select id="selectT4"
                                                                         class="form-control"
                                >

                                </select>
                                <label for="aantalT4">Aantal:</label><input id="aantalT4"
                                                                            class="form-control"
                                                                            type="number"
                                                                            value="1"
                                />

                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="addT4('')"
                                            id="addT4button">
                                        Voeg
                                        toe!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gadgets">
                                <label for="selectGadget">Gadget:</label><select id="selectGadget"
                                                                                 class="form-control"
                                >

                                </select>
                                <label for="aantalGadget">Aantal:</label><input id="aantalGadget"
                                                                                class="form-control"
                                                                                type="number"
                                                                                value="1"
                                />

                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="addGadget('')"
                                            id="addGadgetbutton">
                                        Voeg
                                        toe!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="lossestukken">
                                <label for="refLosstuk">Code</label><input id="refLosstuk" type="text"
                                                                           class="form-control">
                                <label for="descLosstuk">Omschrijving</label><input id="descLosstuk" type="text"
                                                                                    class="form-control">
                                <label for="aantalLosstuk">Aantal:</label><input id="aantalLosstuk"
                                                                                 class="form-control"
                                                                                 type="number"
                                                                                 value="1"
                                />
                                <label for="priceLosstuk">Prijs</label><input id="priceLosstuk" type="text"
                                                                              class="form-control">

                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="addLosstuk('')"
                                            id="addLosstukbutton">
                                        Voeg
                                        toe!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="artikelenVoucher">
                                <div class="container-fluid">

                                    <label for="selectcatagorievoucher">Categorie</label><select
                                        class="form-control" id="selectcatagorievoucher">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteer een
                                            categorie
                                        </option>
                                        <?php

                                        foreach (db_select("SELECT * FROM presse_wit_categorie ORDER BY code ASC ") as $item) {
                                            echo '<option ';
                                            echo 'value = "' . $item['GUID'] . '">';
                                            echo '(' . $item['code'] . ') ' . $item['description'];
                                            echo '</ option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                                    <label for="selectproductvoucher">Product</label><select
                                        id="selectproductvoucher"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        style="visibility: hidden">

                                    </select>

                                    <label for="aantalproductvoucher">Aantal</label><input
                                        id="aantalproductvoucher"
                                        class="form-control"

                                        type="number"
                                        value="1"/>

                                    <br>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                                    onclick="addProductVoucher('')"
                                                    id="addproductvoucherbutton">
                                                Voeg
                                                toe!
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                            <label for="remainingVoucher">Overblijvend:</label><input
                                                type="text"
                                                id="remainingVoucher"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                value="€ 0,00"
                                                disabled>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                            <label for="totaalVoucher">Totaal:</label><input type="text"
                                                                                             id="totaalVoucher"
                                                                                             class="form-control"
                                                                                             value="€ 0,00"
                                                                                             disabled>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Overzichten
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="productenoverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="productstable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="productstablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="promotiesoverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="promotiestable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="promotiestablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sterartikelkenoverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="sterartikelentable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Ster</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="sterartikelentablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="T4overzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="T4table" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="T4tablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gadgetoverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="gadgetstable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="gadgetstablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="lossestukkenoverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="lossestukkentable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="lossestukkentablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="artikelenvouchersvoucheroverzicht">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="artikelenvoucherstable" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Code</th>
                                            <th>Beschrijving</th>
                                            <th>Prijs</th>
                                            <th>Aantal</th>
                                            <th>Totaal</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="artikelenvoucherstablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Totalen
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="totaalArtikelen">Totaal artikelen:</label><input type="text"
                                                                                                 id="totaalArtikelen"
                                                                                                 name="totaalArtikelen"
                                                                                                 class="form-control"
                                                                                                 value="€ 0,00"
                                                                                                 disabled>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="totaalPromoties">Totaal promoties:</label><input type="text"
                                                                                                 id="totaalPromoties"
                                                                                                 name="totaalPromoties"
                                                                                                 class="form-control"
                                                                                                 value="€ 0,00"
                                                                                                 disabled>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="totaalGadgets">Totaal gadgets:</label><input type="text"
                                                                                             id="totaalGadgets"
                                                                                             name="totaalGadgets"
                                                                                             class="form-control"
                                                                                             value="€ 0,00"
                                                                                             disabled>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="totaalLossestukken">Totaal lossestukken:</label><input
                                        type="text"
                                        id="totaalLossestukken"

                                        name="totaalLossestukken"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        value="€ 0,00"
                                        disabled>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="totaalT1">Totaal T1</label><input id="totaalT1"
                                                                                      name="totaalT1"
                                                                                      type="text"
                                                                                      class="form-control"
                                                                                      value="€ 0,00" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="totaalT4">Totaal T4:</label><input type="text"
                                                                                   id="totaalT4"
                                                                                   name="totaalT4"
                                                                                   class="form-control"
                                                                                   value="€ 0,00"
                                                                                   disabled>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="totaalSterren">Totaal Sterren</label><input id="totaalSterren"
                                                                                            name="totaalSterren"
                                                                                            type="text"
                                                                                            class="form-control"
                                                                                            value="0" disabled>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="algemeenTotaal">Algemeen Totaal:</label><input
                                        id="algemeenTotaal"
                                        name="algemeenTotaal"
                                        type="text"
                                        class="form-control text-primary"
                                        value="€ 0,00" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[This is an image of what is happening and what I would like to achieve:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41VHm.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post a specific code snippet which you think contains the problem. This code is too big. Use *Inspect Element* or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a demo fiddle or something would have helped but still...
to get the 3rd div below the 1st you need to have something like this..

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
            /********* DIV 1 HERE *************/
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
            /********* DIV 3 HERE ***************/
       </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
            /********* DIV 2 HERE ************/
       </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Hope it helps.Let me know if it aint clear!

Answer (score 0):

You can add css for third div:

```
clear: both;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid system of bootstrap.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
        <h1>
          DIV 1
        </h1>
        <h1>
          DIV 1
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:green;">
        <h1>
          DIV 2
        </h1>
        <h1>
          DIV 2
        </h1>
        <h1>
          DIV 2
        </h1>
        <h1>
          DIV 2
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
      <h1>
        DIV 3
      </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```